# Creating Webservice Client from wsdl url

Tags: java, web-services, exception

I am new to Java(learning) and i'm trying to create web service client from the wsdl url in netbeans 6.8. I could import all the request by following a tutorial described in this url http://netbeans2.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html. But, when I run a main project I am getting the following exception:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 302: Moved Temporarily
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:196)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:168)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
        at $Proxy28.createSV(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone tell me  why i'm getting this exception.Your suggestion will help a lot.

Thanks,
shashi

Comment: which URL of wsdl you have used?

Comment: I used a url which looks something like this https//host19.sharevault.net/path/srvault.wsdl

Answer (score 1):

A 302 error means the web server thinks the page has moved.  http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E302.html

I bet either you typed in the page wrong, or whoever setup the url didn't update it's redirection when the page was setup.

Btw, you should be able to see a wsdl resolve in a browser as XML if you want to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JBoss? This is a known issue in JBoss 5.1.x

Either comment out the line

```
<property name="webServiceHost">${jboss.bind.address}</property>
```

in

```
APPSRV_HOME/server/default/deployers/jbossws.deployer/META-INF/jboss-beans.xml
```

or switch to a newer version of JBoss.